# Pandas, how to dropna values using subset with multiindex dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nan

I have a data frame with multi-index columns.

From this data frame I need to remove the rows with NaN values in a subset of columns.

I am trying to use the `subset` option of `pd.dropna` but I do not manage to find the way to specify the subset of columns. I have tried using `pd.IndexSlice` but this does not work.

In the example below I need to get ride of the last row.

```
import pandas as pd

# ---
a = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
b = ["a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"]
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([a[:], b[:]])
val = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [None, None, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    [None, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [None, None, 5, 3, 3, 2],
    [None, None, None, None, 5, 7],
]
# ---
df = pd.DataFrame(val, columns=col)
# ---
print(df)
# ---
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.dropna(axis=0, how="all", subset=idx[1:2, :])
# ---
print(df)
```

Using the `thresh` option is an alternative but if possible I would like to use `subset` and `how='all'`

Comment: You want to treat all columns with level 0= 1 or 2, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When dealing with a MultiIndex, each column of the MultiIndex can be specified as a tuple:

```
In [67]: df.dropna(axis=0, how="all", subset=[(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b')])
Out[67]: 
     1         2       3   
     a    b    a    b  a  b
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5  6
1  NaN  NaN  1.0  2.0  3  4
2  NaN  1.0  2.0  3.0  4  5
3  NaN  NaN  5.0  3.0  3  2
```

Or, to select all columns whose first level equals `1` or `2` you could use:

```
In [69]: df.dropna(axis=0, how="all", subset=df.loc[[], [1,2]].columns)
Out[69]: 
     1         2       3   
     a    b    a    b  a  b
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5  6
1  NaN  NaN  1.0  2.0  3  4
2  NaN  1.0  2.0  3.0  4  5
3  NaN  NaN  5.0  3.0  3  2
```

`df[[1,2]].columns` also works, but this returns a (possibly large) intermediate DataFrame. `df.loc[[], [1,2]].columns` is more memory-efficient since its intermediate DataFrame is empty.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply the `dropna` to the columns which have 1 or 2 in level 1, you can do it as follows:

```
cols= [(c0, c1) for (c0, c1) in df.columns if c0 in [1,2]]
df.dropna(axis=0, how="all", subset=cols)
```

If applied to your data, it results in:

```
Out[446]: 
     1         2       3   
     a    b    a    b  a  b
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5  6
1  NaN  NaN  1.0  2.0  3  4
2  NaN  1.0  2.0  3.0  4  5
3  NaN  NaN  5.0  3.0  3  2
```

As you can see, the last line (index=4) is gone, because all columns below 1 and 2 were `NaN` for this line. If you rather want all rows to be removed, where any `NaN` occured in the column, you need:

```
df.dropna(axis=0, how="any", subset=cols)
```

Which results in:

```
Out[447]: 
     1         2       3   
     a    b    a    b  a  b
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5  6
```